# Split datetime interval by minutes based on duration SQL server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table that looks like below, i am trying to split it up by the duration column so i get, in the example below, 60 rows but for each minute time interval, meaning the time would increase by one minute.

```
Filmtitle                   startTime                   duration
----------------------------------------------------------------
WW2's most daring raids     2016-10-03 00:00:00.000        60
```

Desired results:

```
WW2's most daring raids     2016-10-03 00:00:01.000        60
WW2's most daring raids     2016-10-03 00:00:02.000        60
...
WW2's most daring raids     2016-10-03 00:00:59.000        60
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a TVF which may help.  It is used to create dynamic date ranges.  A Tally/Numbers table will do the trick as well.

```
Declare @YourTable table (Filmtitle varchar(100),startTime datetime,duration int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('WW2''s most daring raids','2016-10-03 00:00:00.000',60)

Select A.Filmtitle
      ,SomeName=B.RetVal
      ,A.duration
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](A.startTime,DateAdd(MI,A.Duration-1,A.startTime),'MI',1) B
```

Returns

```
Filmtitle               SomeName                duration
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:00:00.000 60
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:01:00.000 60
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:02:00.000 60
---
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:57:00.000 60
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:58:00.000 60
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:59:00.000 60
```

The function if Needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the UDF another option is an ad-hoc tally table

```
Declare @YourTable table (Filmtitle varchar(100),startTime datetime,duration int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('WW2''s most daring raids','2016-10-03 00:00:00.000',60)

Select A.Filmtitle
      ,SomeName=DateAdd(MI,RN,startTime)
      ,A.duration
 From @YourTable A
 Join (
        Select RN=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select Null))
         From (Select N=1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)) A
         Join (Select N=1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)) B on 1=1
       ) B on 1=1
 Where B.RN<A.duration
```

Returns

```
Filmtitle               SomeName                duration
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:00:00.000 60
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:01:00.000 60
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:02:00.000 60
---
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:57:00.000 60
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:58:00.000 60
WW2's most daring raids 2016-10-03 00:59:00.000 60
```

Comment: Thanks John, didnt quite understand your first, but the second answer kinda did the trick, however i am getting duplicate rows of time. any ideas?

Comment: @eddieB Huh,  Try Select Distinct A.Filmtitle ...   Keep the UDF in your pocket.  I get a tremendous amount of use from it.

Comment: Sorry nevermind, just realised that i actually have duplicate rows due to previuos excercise :) many thanks for this!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. the idea is to convert the duration to equivalent number of rows numbered from one to Duration -1. then add the row_number to the startdate.

```
declare @table table(Film varchar(50), StartDate datetime, duration int)
insert into @table values
('WW2''s most daring raids', '2016-10-03 00:00:00.000', 60)


;with cte as(
    select Film, StartDate, cast(Replicate('<k>1</k>', Duration-1) as xml) as x
    from @table
)
, cte2 as(
  select Film, startdate, 
  ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Film, StartDate order by (select null)) as RN
  from cte 
  outer apply x.nodes('/k') t(Dur)
) 
select Film, Startdate, dateadd(second, RN, StartDate) as EndDate
from cte2 as a
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, it seems to work, but i cannot understand how, way too advanced for me :)

Comment: Actually, cte will create in addition to your File and StartDate a new XML column contains 59 replicated entires of '<k>1</k>'. cte2 will OUTER APPLY them to convert them to rows numbered from 1 to 59 by the ROW_NUMBER function. Then in the final SELECT, simply DateAdd this row number to your StartDate to get the required result.